# Nethereum.KeyStore.KeyStoreService.DecryptKeyStoreFromJson seems too slow on Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, solidity

we do key encyption/decryption roughly as following.

key creation and encrypting as keystore

```
var key = Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey.GenerateKey();
var service = new Nethereum.KeyStore.KeyStoreService();
var keyStore = service.EncryptAndGenerateDefaultKeyStoreAsJson(
            password, key.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes(), key.GetPublicAddress());
```

key recovery from keystore to create EthECKey

```
var service = new Nethereum.KeyStore.KeyStoreService();
key = new Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey(
        service.DecryptKeyStoreFromJson(password, keyStore), 
        true);
```

key encyption also seems to take long time, but I think its ok because typically this is only done 1st time.

problem is key recovery from keystore (always needed when app launches) takes more than 10 seconds at UnityEditor (2017.3.1) on my machine (macbook pro late 2015, 16GB ram and 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7, High Sierra), which will harm UX a lot.

if I just store `key.GetPrivateKey()` and do `new Nethereum.Signer.EthECKey(privateKey)` for recovering key, it finishes immediately, so I guess this caused by slow decryption speed.

so question is:

1. this (>10 seconds) is normal decryption speed for my environment?
2. if 1. is correct, any suggestion to speed up? (maybe a few seconds is limit)
3. if 1. is not correct, any idea about what I am missing?

Comment: I would like to know too, did you find the answer?

Comment: @RichardFu sadly, nope. I also post it github (https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/issues/288), but not so much help. current my workaround is store private key with lighter encryption.